# SF2 services and doctrine

Tags: symfony

Welcome,

I created a few projects in sf2 (2.4-2.8). The code was different quality...
I read few articles. Now I try to minimize the code in the controller. I use Repository, Services etc. When I use with the services, don't injects doctrine, forwards object. In the controller initializes forms, objects, services, check validation forms and returns values to template. But I have functionalities which I must generate query in the loop or I need many query, which can not be combined into one. 
My structure folder: Controller, Services, Repository, Entity, Form, Resources.
How can I reconcile all this? Minimum controller, functionalities in the services and Repository to Entity.

Example ugly code controller:

```
/**
   * @Route("/add", name="controller_admin_page_add")
   * @Template()
   * @param Request $request
   */
  public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $page = new Page;
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new FormPage, $page);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->isMethod("POST") && $form->isValid()) {
      $links = $em->createQuery("...")->getResult();
      foreach($link as links){
         if(...){
           $checkLink = $em->createQuery("...")->getResult();
           ...
         }
       .....
      }
      $em->persist($page);
      $em->flush();

      return $this->redirectToRoute('controller_admin_page_index');
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
  }
```

Example nicer code:

```
/** ...
  */
  public function addAction(Request $request) {
    $page = new Page;
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new FormPage, $page);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->isMethod("POST") && $form->isValid()) {
      $generateUrl = $this->container->get('Url');
      $generateUrl->checkLink($page);
      $generateUrl->getUrl();

      $em->persist($page);
      $em->flush();

      return $this->redirectToRoute('controller_admin_page_index');
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
  }
```

Here is problem.

The functionality takes over Services. In the "clean architecture", I should pass an object/objects to the Services. But I must send query in loop.

In my opinion I need 2 types classes helper in project.
1). Gets the object /objects by setters and returns the processed data. Class doesn't have access to the doctrine.
2) Gets arguments, created query and returns the processed data. Class have access to the doctrine.

In the project I have Repository, they only return the objects.

I have a problem with the class name, directory name, and using it.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Perhaps you could update it with a simple example of what   "But I have functionalities which I must generate query in the loop or I need many query, which can not be combined into one" means.

Comment: Ok. I need 2 type class. First: Get object and returns something. Second: gets parameters, it generates the same query and returns something. General, I'm looking for best practices... Now I use services to all. When I need a doctrine, injected EntityManager.I think that is a bad solution.

Comment: Language barrier.  Please update your question with the problem code and perhaps an alternative could be proposed.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Now better?